# Get the following error : Error: Cannot find control with path: 'budgetIncomes -> 0 -> '

Tags: angular, formarray

I get the following error when trying to use formarray with angular 9 :

> Error: Cannot find control with path: 'budgetIncomes -> 0 -> '

I tried evrything but nothing seems to work. I don't understand why the path is not found :

```
<form *ngIf="incomeForm" [formGroup]="incomeForm">
  <div formArrayName="budgetIncomes">
    <h3>Income</h3>
    <div *ngFor="let item of incomesArray.controls; let i=index"[formGroupName]="i">
      <input type="text" [formControlName]="label">
      <input type="number" [formControlName]="somme">
    </div>
    <button (click)="addIncome()">Add Income</button>
  </div>
</form>

<p class="result"  [ngStyle]="{'color': getSum()>=0? 'green' : 'red'}">{{getSum()}}</p>
```

and the .ts :

```
import { Component, OnInit, SimpleChanges  } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { FormArray } from '@angular/forms';
import { Budget } from '../budget';


export interface BudgetIncomes {
  label: string;
  somme: number;
}

const ELEMENT_DATA: BudgetIncomes[] = [
  {label: 'Hydrogen',  somme: 10},
];

@Component({
  selector: 'app-income',
  templateUrl: './income.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./income.component.scss']
})


export class IncomeComponent implements OnInit {

  incomeForm: FormGroup;
  sum;



  getSum() {
    // 1st way
    return this.incomesArray.value.reduce((prev, next) => prev + +next, 0);

  }

  createBudget(): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group(ELEMENT_DATA.map(x => new FormGroup({
        label : new FormControl(x.label),
        somme : new FormControl(x.somme),
      })
    ));
  }

  get incomesArray(): FormArray {
    return this.incomeForm.get('budgetIncomes') as FormArray;
  }

  addIncome() {
    this.incomesArray.push(this.fb.group(this.createBudget()));
  }


  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.incomeForm = this.fb.group({
      budgetIncomes: this.fb.array(ELEMENT_DATA.map(x => new FormGroup({
          label : new FormControl(x.label),
          somme : new FormControl(x.somme),
        })
      ))
    });
  }

}
```

Here the link to a stackblitz : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9vk1nr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you use `[formControlName]="label"`, which is **property binding**, meaning that it will look for a property called `label` inside your component class.

The solution would be to use **static binding**: `formControlName="label"` and `formControlName="somme"`.

Comment: Thx for the fast answer ! It does work now with the initial field. But when I add one, I got the same error : Error: Cannot find control with path: 'budgetIncomes -> 1 -> label' ??

Comment: I was able to correct it by changing my code. But I do not understand why it does not work with the previous one. So if you can explain me, I'll be glad :D

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Hope [this](https://www.telerik.com/blogs/understanding-angular-property-binding-and-interpolation) will clarify some things. If not, let me know!